# MongoDb 4.x Query with projection without empty entries using find

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, mongo-projection

We are now using mongo-db to store data from tests. I am using Mongo-Shell
The document is structured like this:

```
{
   static1:"abc",
   static2:"xyz",
   static3:"asd", [...],
   nested:[
   {
       data1: "d1",
       data2: "d2",
   },
   {
       data1: "dx",
       data4: "d4",
       data5: "d5",
       data6: "d6",
   },
   {
       data1: "ds",
       data8:"data8"
   }, [...]
   ]
}
```

So the static-data is always in the same structure, but for every measurement the object can look different. It could be voltage with upper, lower and actual value. Or just comparison of a target value and an actual value. Highly dynamic.
Same data1-name represent same attributes.

Now e.g. I want to display only some static data and one (or several) attributes of a nested document.

I am using this query:

```
find({}, {_id:0, data1:1, "nested.data8":1}).pretty()
```

As expected, only the static-data1 is displayed, but the dynamic measurements has lots of empty objects in the shell-output

Example-Output:

```
{ 
  "static1" : "123", 
  "nested" : [
    {  }, 
    {  }, 
    {  }, [...] ,
    { "data8" : "OK" } 
] }
```

The desired output would be:

```
{ 
   "static1" : "123", 
   "nested" : [
         { "data8" : "d8" } 
    ] 
}
```

I also tried this query on the mongo shell:

```
aggregate( { $addFields: {"static":"$static1", "data8":"$nested.data8"} },  { $project:{"static1":1, "nested.data8":1} } ).pretty()
```

But the result is the same.
I hope there is a ways to get rid of the empty documents in the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$filter` operator to filter result of `nested` array by checking condition not equal to empty object `{}`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data1: 1,
      "nested.data8": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      nested: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$nested",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", {}] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KaIAXh0D-Oh)